# how to get past newsfeed using facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications

the API to fetch newsfeed is: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=&limit=1000&untill=

which returns paginated feed output with 'next' url to fetch previous feeds.

However it stops returning newsfeed beyond a certain time. So newsfeed of few days is only available for parsing.

Is there a way out to get more historical newsfeed using facebook apis???

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [graph API documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), `/me/home` is limited to only 1-2 weeks of history, and it has fallen into the "we don't care about this" category:

> `/me/home` retrieves an outdated view of the News Feed. This is currently a known issue and we don't have any near term plans to bring them back up into parity.

Use `/me/feed` instead.

You can use the `since` and `until` parameters to get historical data from a user's feed. This will get you the posts that appeared between August 15-20, 2012.

```
/me/feed?since=2012-08-15&until=2012-08-20
```

The data returned by `/me/feed/` is also limited. The limits aren't explicitly stated, but I never expect to be able to access more than 30 days worth of posts from one API call.

Comment: me/feed doesn't contain friend's stories.. if somebody posted a picture, it will be part of me/home only not me/feed.  me/feed only talks about my wall.  But i need historical data of my friend's stories....

Comment: Try using the [FQL stream table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) instead. You can restrict this to posts by others using the `WHERE filter_key='others'`