# stream feeds older than an month are not returned using FQL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am getting stream feeds using this query

```
SELECT 
   post_id, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment,
   permalink, type , created_time,timeline_visibility,updated_time 
FROM
   stream 
WHERE 
   filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()) 
   and (updated_time < 1363762637 AND updated_time > 1364540237)
```

This query returns result accurately when updated_time exists within current month, Problem is that when i give the updated_time older than a 30 days no record is returned.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve home newsfeed or your timeline feed?

Comment: news feed on my wall..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113561/189673

Answer (score 1):

Their new API documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream doesn't explain '2 weeks' limitation, so i give example of Search:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/:

> Please note, you can only search about 1 to 2 weeks back in the News Feed.

Similar dicussion here: [how to get past newsfeed using facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709863/how-to-get-past-newsfeed-using-facebook-api)

Even you using the web browser is same, impossible you're able to get all news feed since 3 or 4 years ago by just click the "More stories".